# Extract board outline of an PCB

Tags: python, coordinates, circuit

I have a problem that i can´t reach the exact dimensions of the x and y of the PCB Schematic in mm or inch.

The method that I was using is, it starts by opening the file, and then reads each line. If the line starts with `G36`, it means that the parsing of the outline has started. If the line starts with `G37`, it means that the parsing of the outline has ended. If the line starts with `X`, it means that it contains coordinates, in the following code:

```python
def extract_coordinates_from_line(line):
    # Extract X and Y coordinates from a line
    parts = line[1:].split("Y")
    try:
        x = float(parts[0])
        y = float(parts[1].split("D")[0])
        return x, y
    except ValueError:
        # Handle the case where the conversion fails
        return None

def extract_board_outline(gerber_file_path):
    board_outline = []
    parsing_outline = False

    with open(gerber_file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if "G36" in line:
                parsing_outline = True
            elif "G37" in line:
                parsing_outline = False
            elif parsing_outline and line.startswith("X"):
                coordinates = extract_coordinates_from_line(line)
                if coordinates:
                    board_outline.append(coordinates)

    return board_outline

def calculate_board_size(board_outline, scale_factor=1):  # Assuming the default unit is inches
    if not board_outline:
        return 0, 0

    min_x = min(point[0] for point in board_outline)
    max_x = max(point[0] for point in board_outline)
    min_y = min(point[1] for point in board_outline)
    max_y = max(point[1] for point in board_outline)

    width = (max_x - min_x) * scale_factor
    height = (max_y - min_y) * scale_factor

    return width, height

def main():
    gerber_file_path = 'top2.gbr'  # Replace with the actual path to your Gerber file
    board_outline = extract_board_outline(gerber_file_path)

    if not board_outline:
        print("No board outline found in the Gerber file.")
    else:
        print("Board Outline Coordinates:")
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(board_outline, start=1):
            print(f"Point {i}: X={x}, Y={y}")

        width, height = calculate_board_size(board_outline)
        width /= 100
        height /= 100
        width *= 1.36
        height *= 1.36
        print(f"\nBoard Size: Width={width}, Height={height}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I already define the separation of the value in `mm` and value with `inch`, and I'm using the `Top.gbr` file to get the outline information.

```
ADD:G04 DipTrace 4.0.0.5*
G04 1 - Top.gbr*
%MOMM*%
G04 #@! TF.FileFunction,Copper,L1,Top*
G04 #@! TF.Part,Single*
G04 #@! TA.AperFunction,Conductor*
%ADD15C,0.989*%
%ADD16C,0.789*%
G04 #@! TA.AperFunction,CopperBalancing*
%ADD18C,0.935*%
G04 #@! TA.AperFunction,ComponentPad*
%ADD21R,1.5X1.5*%
%ADD22C,1.5*%
%ADD23R,1.7X1.7*%
%ADD24C,1.7*%
%ADD25R,2.5X2.5*%
%ADD26C,2.5*%
%ADD27C,1.27*%
%ADD28R,1.27X1.27*%
%ADD29O,2.2X3.6*%
%ADD30C,1.524*%
%ADD31C,1.524*%

%ADD32R,1.6X1.6*%
%ADD33C,1.6*%
%ADD34C,1.5*%
G04 #@! TA.AperFunction,ViaPad*
%ADD35C,1.016*%
%ADD76C,0.31373*%
%FSLAX35Y35*%
```

Comment: What is the expected output when running the code? What is the actual output when running the code? Are you getting any errors (probably not, you seem to be swallowing exceptions and simply returning `None`, bad idea)? Can you [edit] your question to include the contents of the `Top.gbr` file (if it's not too long, like MB in size)?

Comment: Actually what i would be expecting from  a X=132.9 mm  Y=125.7mm

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the contents of the `Top.gbr` file or `top2.gbr` file (if they're not too large, like MB in size)?

Comment: Sorry is bit too long , i cant include it

Comment: but i can provide the inicial ADD of the PCB

Comment: Can you add the line starting with `G36` and the 10 lines after it, and the line starting with `G37` and the 10 lines before it, from `Top.gbr` or `top2.gbr`, to your question?

Comment: Have you looked into using [pcb-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pcb-tools/) to read your gerber file?

Comment: `calculate_board_size` has a comment `# assuming the default unit is inches`, but your *"initial ADD of the PCB"* contains `%MOMM*%` which [the spec](https://www.ucamco.com/files/downloads/file_en/456/gerber-layer-format-specification-revision-2022-02_en.pdf#page=24?ac97011bf6bce9aaf0b1aac43d84b05f) annotates with *"Unit set to mm"*, perhaps you shouldn't be scaling `width` and `height` to millimeters in your `main()` function, instead just see what `calculate_board_size` returns without scaling.

Comment: Its an result some much more huge if i do that ,but thx.I have done some reasearch and i hava found if i wanted to make this code work,it wont be with G36 AND G37 cause not every top.grb file have this Gs.